# ¿Cómo trabajo con dos plantillas en Inertia - Laravel?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-8, inertia.js

el problema que tengo es que en la app.blade.php estoy cargando los css y js de las dos plantillas y eso causa conflicto, alguien tiene alguna idea de que hacer en ese caso?

Estoy trabajando Laravel + Vue con Inertia.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hice de la siguiente forma: en el archivo HandleinertiaResquest.php creé una función de la siguiente forma (la coloqué al final, luego de la función share):

```
public function rootView(Request $request)
{
    if($request->is(['dashboard', 'dashboard/*', 'login', 'register', 'admin'])){
        return 'app';
    }

    return 'appFront';
}
```

En el request reviso hacia dónde voy a ir y le digo qué plantilla voy a utilizar: por ejemplo, todo mi admin, dashboard, login y register se va a manejar con la plantilla predeterminada y para las vistas del front creé una plantilla.